# how to use single string var in url instead of multple when pushing something to php?

Tags: php

how do you setup PHP to do use single string in url: ex just ?small instead of the code below

```
if ( $_GET['api_img_size'] == 'small' ) { ....
```

but with ?small do the same thing as the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if ( isset( $_GET['small'] ) ) {
  //?small or ?small=1 or ?small=WHATEVER
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( isset($_GET['small']) ) { ....
```